# Parsley.js strips plus sign (+) from emails in Safari/Firefox?

Tags: jquery, validation, firefox, safari, parsley.js

I'm running into an odd error that is hopefully easy to solve. While people having emails with + signs in them is probably not too common, that is one way that I go about testing my form submissions. Also, if it's stripping other characters that I just haven't tested with yet, that's obviously an issue too.

Basically, say I use: test.email@gmail.com. It submits fine, all good. If I use test.email+2@gmail.com, it appears in my CRM as "test.email", so everything after the + is removed as well. If I open up the form submission in the contact record, it shows up as "test.email 2@gmail.com", with the space where the + was.

This does not happen in Chrome, but does happen in Safari and Firefox. I should also mention that this is being validated within a modal, which is why the fields are initially using `data-parsley-excluded`. Those attributes are being removed with jQuery and then the required attribute is being added.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" id="become-sponsor-form"  class="x-form" method="POST" novalidate>
                        <input name="x-name" type="hidden" value="xxxx" />
                        <input name="x-name2" type="hidden" value="X Value" />
                        <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-warning invisible mx-auto">
                            <p>Please fill out all required fields.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" placeholder="Kevin" data-parsley-trigger='change' data-parsley-excluded data-parsley-group='block1'/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" placeholder='Bacon' data-parsley-trigger='change' data-parsley-excluded data-parsley-group='block1'/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Email">Email</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" type="email" placeholder="kevinbacon@yourcompany.com" data-parsley-type='email' data-parsley-trigger='change' data-parsley-excluded data-parsley-group='block1'/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Phone1">Phone</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="Phone1" minlength = '10' maxlength="14" data-parsley-error-message='Must be minimum of 10 digits' data-parsley-trigger='change' data-parsley-excluded data-parsley-group='block1'/>
                            <input id="hidden-number" name='Phone1' type="hidden" name="phone-full">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="CompanyType">Type of Business</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="CompanyType" name="CompanyType" type="text" placeholder='Ecommerce, Marketing Agency, etc.' data-parsley-trigger='change' data-parsley-excluded data-parsley-group='block1'/>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"/>
                    </form>
```

And here is the JS in case you need that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#become-sponsor-btn').on('click', function() {

            $("#FirstName, #LastName, #Email, #Phone1, #CompanyType").attr("required", true);

            $("#FirstName, #LastName, #Email, #Phone1, #CompanyType").removeAttr("data-parsley-excluded");

            $('#become-sponsor-form').parsley().on('field:validated', function() {
                var ok = $('.parsley-error').length === 0;
                if (this.$element.hasClass('parsley-error')) {
                    $('.bs-callout-warning').toggleClass('invisible', ok);
                };
            }); 
        });

        $("#become-sponsor-form").on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#become-sponsor-form').parsley().on('form:validate', function (formInstance) {
                var success = formInstance.isValid({group: 'block1'});
                console.log(success);
                if (success) {
                    var form_data = $("#become-sponsor-form").serialize();

                     $("#become-sponsor-form").html('<div class="loading_message text-center"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i></div>');
                     $.post("formaction.php", form_data, function(result){
                        $("#become-sponsor-form").html('<div class="success_message alert alert-success text-center" role="alert">Thank You.. We will contact you soon...</div>');
                    });

                } else {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;                   
                }

            });
        });

    });
```

I'm not too familiar with cross-browser compatibility with forms and thought that adding `novalidate` to the form might fix the issue, but that wasn't quite the case.
Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: `+` is a substitute for space in URL-encoded format. But `.serialize()` should encode the `+` sign in the values, so this is not supposed to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Parsley. Remove parsley and you'll have the same issue.

This has everything to do with you trying to re-do what the browser can do for you when posting your results. In particular:

```
$('<form><input name="foo" value="a+b"></form>').serialize()  // => "foo=a%2Bb"
```

You may want to rethink your approach and use a solution that does the submitting for you correctly, like [rails-ujs](https://github.com/rails/rails-ujs) does for remote form. You'll note that they had to write [their own serializer](https://github.com/rails/rails-ujs/blob/master/src/utils/form.coffee#L7-L27). You could probably use `rails-ujs` directly. If you bind Parsley first it should interact nicely.

Comment: Marc-André, thank you for your comment! This is a bit of legacy code that I'm trying to apply form validation to (and am relatively new to the programming world in general), so I'm still not too sure of where to go from here. By letting me know that it's definitely not a Parsley error though, that at least rules out one culprit, so I'll look more into cross-browser form submission and best practices in that area. Thanks again!